# Localstorage doesn't load until page reload

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to log in my user and then display their name in the navigation bar. In my service i set localstorage user. Then i have this code in my component:

```
onLoginSubmit() {
    this.submitted = true;
    this.mainService.loginUser(this.loginForm.value.username, this.loginForm.value.password).subscribe(
        data => {
            this.user = data.data;
            this.router.navigate(['/']);
        }, error => {
            this.errorAtLogin = error.error.errorUser;
        }, () => {
    });
}
```

I don't want to reload the page because it looks pretty clunky and it flashes the screen and rebuilds it.  However if i reload the page after router.navigate it works.

So my questions are:

- what am i doing wrong?
- why doesn't localstorage item set itself when i call it? And why does it need page reload to work?

Comment: Can you share the code where you are setting and getting local storage data?

Comment: What is this mainService will do ? Please share mainService class, is this a rest call , why your subscribing to that service.